# Flutter: too many variables in widget constructor from paren widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have many callbacks and variables in stateless widget constructor from stateful parent. What solutions exist besides InheritedWidget?
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
class ContragentCreateTabs extends StatelessWidget {
  ContragentCreateTabs({
    required this.activeTab,
    required this.onChangeTab,
    required this.onChangeCurrency,
    required this.onChangeFi,
    required this.fis,
    required this.currencies,
    required this.numberController,
    required this.fiCodeController,
    required this.entityId,
    this.chosenCurrency,
    this.chosenFi,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);
```

Comment: can you include code-snippet instead of code-image that will reproduce the same error

Comment: and how you are using `ContragentCreateTabs` that reproducing the error ?